# find the average using jess or clips

Tags: average, clips, jess

This is clips code to find the average ... but it dose not work ... can anyone know how to fix it ??

```
(deftemplate fact (slot name) (slot value))
    (deftemplate avg (slot result))
    (deffacts data
       (fact (name data-1) (value 3))
       (fact (name data-2) (value 1))
       (fact (name data-3) (value 2))
       (fact (name data-4) (value 2))
       (fact (name data-5) (value 4))
       (fact (name data-6) (value 3)))

    (deffact sum (avg (result 0))

    (defrule find-avg
       (fact (name ?name1) (value ?value1))  
       (avg (modify (result (+ result ?value1))
       ))

    (defrule finding-avg
        (avg (modify (result (/ result 6)))
    ))
```

Comment: The code you've posted here is very far from syntactically correct Jess. Even a cursory look at the Jess manual should tell you that a rule has two parts separated by `=>`.

Answer (score 1):

In CLIPS, you can use the fact query functions to do this:

```
CLIPS> (deftemplate fact (slot name) (slot value))
CLIPS> (deftemplate avg (slot result))
CLIPS> 
(deffacts data
   (fact (name data-1) (value 3))
   (fact (name data-2) (value 1))
   (fact (name data-3) (value 2))
   (fact (name data-4) (value 2))
   (fact (name data-5) (value 4))
   (fact (name data-6) (value 3)))
CLIPS> 
(deffunction average (?template ?slot)
   (bind ?sum 0)
   (bind ?count 0)
   (do-for-all-facts ((?f ?template)) TRUE
      (bind ?sum (+ ?sum (fact-slot-value ?f ?slot)))
      (bind ?count (+ ?count 1)))
   (if (= ?count 0)
      then FALSE
      else (/ ?sum ?count)))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (assert (avg (result (average fact value))))
<Fact-7>
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (fact (name data-1) (value 3))
f-2     (fact (name data-2) (value 1))
f-3     (fact (name data-3) (value 2))
f-4     (fact (name data-4) (value 2))
f-5     (fact (name data-5) (value 4))
f-6     (fact (name data-6) (value 3))
f-7     (avg (result 2.5))
For a total of 8 facts.
CLIPS>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `accumulate` to count and sum slot `value` over all `fact` facts.

```
(defrule find-avg
    ?avg <- (accumulate
            (progn (bind ?sum 0)(bind ?count 0))
            (progn (bind ?sum (+ ?sum ?value))(++ ?count))
            (/ ?sum ?count)
            (fact (value ?value)))
=>
    (printout t "average " ?avg crlf)
)
```

`progn` is required for grouping function calls. Functions `progn`, `bind` etc. as well as `accumulate` is all very well documented in the Jess manual so I'm not going to repeat that here.